# Free-Fall Lab Help - Getting weird results

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, kinematics, free-fall, data-analysis

So, I am doing a free-fall lab for my physics class. We got the values and I have the results here(we used a infrared photo-gate). Basically, we have a brass cylinder and a wood cylinder. Each are dropped in the middle of 4 infrared photo-gates before hitting the ground, which calculate the velocities and the time at which they passed through.

[image]

We had 4 trials done(the recommended amount). We needed to calculate the acceleration to determine whether it was approximately equal to 9.81 m/s^2. However, when calculating the acceleration, we got weird results.

First, we decided to subtract the velocities between gates and subtract the times between and then divide the velocity change by the time difference and here is one result we got that makes no sense: 31.13 m/s^2.

We then decided to calculate it as if we are going from 0 velocity to N velocity, the results we got. We got better results, but they had an increasing acceleration. Here is the first set of results: 10.18 m/s^2, 13.96 m/s^2, 15.63 m/s^2, 19.8 m/s^2.

I will try using averaging, but I wanted to make sure I calculated the results correctly. Is there a mistake that was made?

Comment: What was the spacing between the gates? How was the velocity calculated? It looks like "user error" but without more details about the setup that is hard to judge.

Comment: Were you given any instructions on how to do the data analysis? The usual method of doing this is by curve fitting, but I don't know which grade you are in and if they expect you to know how to do that. If you are in high school then you are not required to know this, if you are doing this in college, then I would strongly advise that curve fitting be the taught for this kind of data analysis problem.

Comment: I am guessing right now, but if the photogates already measure an instantaneous velocity, then all you have to do is to fit a linear function to the four data points. Did they teach you how to do that? Do you have the formula for that? Practically, if you are not required to reproduce that knowledge in the analysis (in my old physics labs we had to), Excel can do it for you in a graph and there is a formula built in. I am not saying that you should use Excel... just saying that's how somebody who has to do this for a living (rather than a grade) would do it (by using Excel or other tools).

Comment: The gates are telling you about 4-12 m/s velocities. Are those reasonable? Do you understand where they come from? If they are not reasonable, can you figure out what might be wrong and fix it? I am guessing that they are not reasonable and are in fact too high. And not just because your result is too high, but also because if I assigned this experiment in my intro lab the way the students would set it up would generate lower velocities than that.

Comment: In any case, whenever you let the data acquisition system do part of your analysis (as here; it is telling you the velocities) you ***must*** know what it is doing in order to have confidence in your results.

Comment: dmckee and Floris are right. The data looks horrible. Even if we assume that you have a rather high fall tower none of it makes any sense, whatsoever. Were you measuring the velocity in foot/s, or something? Is there a calibration constant that you were supposed to take before the measurement?

Comment: Unless these objects are falling through treacle these data don't make a lot of sense. ;-) What a waste of a data acquisition system!

Comment: Wait... you have five gates, but there are only four times. Are those already the time difference between adjacent gates? Are they they time differences between the first gate and the following four?

Comment: My bad, there are 4 gates.

Comment: The only constant that we had to measure was the diameter of the cylinder, but we measured that approximately, but with a good enough calculation that I don't think that was the issue.

Comment: And what were you supposed to do with that diameter? Does knowing it have a purpose in this measurement? (Also, what was the geometry of this object while it was falling? The way I visualize it the diameter would be useless.)

Comment: How, exactly, are the gates measuring the velocity? Are they, by any chance, using the diameter or length of the cylinder for that measurement? I am imagining, right now, that the gates will return a timing signal, but then it would actually have to get shorter as the cylinders are picking up speed. Is that already taken care off in the software?

Comment: As far as I understand, the diameter of the cylinder was required because when we input it into the software, the software uses it because we turned the cylinder on its side so that it could determine when the cylinder passed the sensor. The software already takes care of a majority of that stuff.

Comment: The software was not, by any chance, expected the radius was it? In any case, you are getting closer to knowing enough to find the problem. Next question: how far from the starting level was the first gate? What we're look for here is what velocity you should be expecting at that gate in the hope that this will point at a simple problem (like diameter versus radius). We could just as easily ask about any other gate for this, so if you feel more confident about a different one, go with that.

Comment: That value of 31.13 m/s^2 sounds amazingly like 32 ft/s^2.  Are you sure that you were using the correct units in your measurement?

Comment: I noticed that when I do get the average slope of the curve, the result is approx 32 m/s^2, which could indicate that. I might note this as an error of speculation.

Comment: @user3864563 That shouldn't be a speculation. Either you measured with the inches side of the stick or the cm side of the stick, and you should know which one. Don't throw speculation onto the page just to have something to write. Well, unless the instructor rewards that kind of nonsense, but at least recognize it for what it is.

Comment: Problem is we can't do any more experiments because of the limited time and we no longer have access to the equipment. He even states that if there is unreasonable data then we have to be honest about the results and give some possible explanation for the results.